# Generating multiple sets of decreasing numbers in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to make multiple sets of randomly generated but decreasing numbers in python?

For example, the first ten numbers of a 100 number sequence should start with a large number and decrease until the tenth. Then, the next ten numbers will follow the same pattern, starting large and decreasing until the 20th, and so on.

This might look something like this:

```
1   100
2   84 
3   66
4   63
5   41
6   35
7   30
8   18
9   9
10  8
11  98 # next sequence starts
12  55
13  54
14  33
15  22
16  11
17  8
18  7
19  5
20  2
```

Ideally, this could be randomly generated for any specified length.

Additional functionality could be provided by generating these decreasing sequences with random lengths.

Comment: What have you tried ? What does not work as you expect ?

Comment: *"make multiple sets of randomly generated but decreasing numbers in python?"* - How does that differ from making **one** such set (and just doing that multiple times)? I.e., why are you asking about multiple instead of just one?

Comment: I'm sure there are a few ways to do this. What have you looked into so far? It's always a good idea to provide a [mre] - even if it doesn't quite work, we might be able to at least tell you where you've gotten stuck. Remember, you can [edit] your question at any time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the numbers to be distinct, which means, at most you can generate 10 sets, here is a way to do it:

```
import random


def gen_sets(n_sets):
    if n_sets>10:
        raise ValueError("n_sets can't be bigger than 100")
    l = list(range(1,100))
    random.shuffle(l)
    for i in range(n_sets):
        yield sorted(l[10*i:10*(i+1)], reverse=True)

my_sets = list(gen_sets(5))
```

- `range` is used to generate the 100 integers. [range doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)
- `random.shuffle` is used to shuffle the elements of the list. [random shuffle doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)
- `sorted` is used to order each set, with `reverse=True` to make it a decreasing order. [sorted doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

Comment: In the example given by obrunt has the value 8 at 10th and 17th. I guess it does not need to be distinct.

Answer (score 1):

I modified Seddik's code to make the function more parameterized.

```py
import itertools
import random

def gen_random_sequences(limit, partitions):
    max_partition_size = limit // 10
    if partitions > max_partition_size:
        raise ValueError(f'Partitions can\'t be larger than {max_partition_size}')
    available = list(range(1, limit + 1))
    random.shuffle(available)
    for partition in range(partitions):
        yield sorted(available[10 * partition:10 * (partition + 1)], reverse=True)

sequences = list(gen_random_sequences(100, 2)) # Matrix

print(sequences)

random_sequence = list(itertools.chain(*sequences)) # Flatten matrix

for i, n in enumerate(random_sequence):
    print(f'{i + 1} {n}')
```

#### Sample output

```
[[95, 85, 76, 71, 49, 42, 39, 33, 16, 1], [100, 92, 77, 64, 63, 48, 41, 40, 18, 15]]
1 95
2 85
3 76
4 71
5 49
6 42
7 39
8 33
9 16
10 1
11 100
12 92
13 77
14 64
15 63
16 48
17 41
18 40
19 18
20 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use choice method of numpy([numpy.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)).
Here is my code:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
import numpy as np

def get_it(high, length, n_repeat, replace=False):
    
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    
    match length:
        case int():
            partial_seqs = [rng.choice(high+1, length, replace=replace) for _ in range(n_repeat)]
        case Sequence():
            partial_seqs = [rng.choice(high+1, 
                                       length[i%len(length)], # circular if len(length) < n_repeat
                                       replace=replace)
                            for i in range(n_repeat)]
        case _:
            raise TypeError('Unsupported type of length')
        
    partial_seqs = [np.flip(np.sort(x)) for x in partial_seqs]
    
    return list(np.concatenate(partial_seqs))

high = 10
length = [5, 3]
n_repeat = 5

get_it(high, length, n_repeat)
```

Sample output:

```
[10, 9, 7, 1, 0, 6, 4, 0, 8, 6, 5, 4, 2, 6, 5, 0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2]
```

If you pass a scalar integer into *length*, then the fixed length will be repeatedly used, e.g., all partial sequences will have the same *length*.

To make partial (sub)sequences with arbitrary lengths, you can pass list-like *length* to the function.
Note that if you give `length = [5, 3]` and `n_repeat = 5`, then to repeat 5 times, it uses *length* in circular manner. In other words, *length* will be expanded to [5, 3, 5, 3, 5]. If you feed like `length = [3, 2, 5]` and `n_repeat = 2`, only first two elements will be used. In other words, `length = [3, 2]` will be used instead.
About *replace*, if you set it as *False*, a subsequence will have unique numbers, i.e., partial sequences will be monotonically-decreasing. Otherwise (e.g., `replace=True`), partial sequences will be decreasing, and there might be the same numbers in a partial sequence.

Answer (score 0):

From the repetition of `8` in your expected result, it seems you don't need the numbers to be distinct across the 10 value chunks. In that case, you can simply use `random.sample` in a loop (or comprehension) to get 10 numbers that you sort before output:

```
from  random import sample
def randChunks(nums,size,count):
    for _ in range(count): 
        yield from sorted(sample(nums,size),reverse=True)
```

output:

```
for i,n in enumerate(randChunks(range(1,96),10,3),1):
    print(i,n)

1 93
2 92
3 88
4 85
5 74
6 62
7 54
8 23
9 15
10 6
11 93
12 76
13 37
14 35
15 28
16 27
17 26
18 18
19 16
20 14
21 85
22 78
23 73
24 70
25 66
26 52
27 40
28 32
29 25
30 19
```

If you need the number to be all different across the chunks, you could use `random.sample` to randomize the whole set of numbers and enumerate to assign group numbers to each chunk.  Sorting the chunks by group number (index divided by size) and negative of value will directly produce the expected chunking and reversed order:

```
from random import sample
def randChunks(nums,size):
    chunks = enumerate(sample(nums,len(nums)))
    return (v for _,v in sorted(chunks,key=lambda x:(x[0]//size,-x[1])))
```

output:

```
for i,n in enumerate(randChunks(range(1,101),10),1):
    print(i,n)
    
1 89
2 88
3 79
4 78
5 72
6 59
7 48
8 40
9 29
10 24
11 82
12 75
13 70
14 60
15 49
16 37
17 22
18 15
19 12
20 2
21 95
22 85
...
95 62
96 50
97 31
98 19
99 16
100 5
```

*If the number of values is not a multiple of the chunk size, the last chunk will be smaller than the specified size. If that is an issue, you can adjust the number of samples on the first line (`len(nums)//size*size` instead of `len(nums)`)*

*Or, you could write the function using zip on multiple copies of an iterator (one copy for each chunk item):*

```
def randChunks(nums,size):
    chunks = size*[iter(sample(nums,len(nums)))]
    return (v for c in zip(*chunks) for v in sorted(c)[::-1])
```